# Hide return Url (%2FAdmin%2FProfile) from Address Bar in .Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, returnurl

I am Passing return Url from my view page to controller using below code.
Now it shows `{ returnUrl=%2FAdmin%2FProfile }` in my address bar. I want to hide it from URL.

```
returnUrl = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"])
```

Comment: Will your STOP undoing the formatting! Not clear what our wanting to do. Your generating it using the code you have shown so of course it will be visible.

Comment: I know that it defiantly shows on url and that's what i want to hide.

Comment: Is there any way to doing that.

Comment: Then don't show it (by removing `returnUrl = ...`)

Comment: If i remove returnUrl  = ....  then how can i come back to same page after Submit button click.See i have two different pages from there i can go to same single page now after clicking submit or cancel it must redirect to the page back from where i came.that's way i am using returnUrl but it showing in url and that's what i want to hide.

Comment: Why? The user will be redirected to that page so they will know what it is, so whats the point? But you can always include a hidden input in the form and store the value in it.

Comment: Let's assume, Current page = A, and Redirected page = B. Now, I want to redirect user from A to B, and I am passing returnUrl as a querystring, because I want to redirect the same user to A after adding the data in B. Now, when I pass redirect from A to B, url shows "returnUrl" parameter. That i want to hide. I have heard, i can achieve it by changing route config.

Comment: No you cant change it using routes. But what is wrong with informing your users?

Comment: I have kind of requirement.Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Read my previous comments. Get the previous url using `Request.Referrer` and add the value to a hidden input in your form and then retrieve it in the POST method.